# Access Vue instance in Nuxt plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

i created a nuxt plugin to use the [simple-jsonrpc-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-jsonrpc-js) package together with the [nuxt auth plugin](https://auth.nuxtjs.org). Now i can access it with `this.$jsonApi.call()` to perform a request to the server with my token provided by nuxt/auth.

I use it in many components within my nuxt app so i wanted to create an error handler for my plugin by wrapping `_jrpc.call()` in a try-catch block. Because im using [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) i want to show a snackbar component with the content of the error Message. Currently my code looks like this:

```js
async call<T = Response<any>>(method: string, data: object = {}): Promise<T> {
    const token = this.accessTokenFactory()
    try {
        return await this._jrpc.call(method, {
            token: token,
            data
        })
    } catch (e:any) {
        const ComponentClass = Vue.extend(VSnackbar)
        const instance = new ComponentClass()
        instance.$slots.default = [e.message]
        instance.$mount()
        document.querySelector('body')?.appendChild(instance.$el)
    }
}
```

But when i get an error from my api, i get this error from the catch block

[image]

Which comes from the vuetify component code:

```js
const {
  bar,
  bottom,
  footer,
  insetFooter,
  left,
  right,
  top,
} = this.$vuetify.application
```

My guess is that the Vue instance i am using doesn't have the `this.$vuetify.application` becuase its not the same as the Vue instance used by the nuxt application...

That's why im asking: how do i access the same Vue instance in Nuxt when injecting a plugin? The Nuxt docs arent helping and i haven't found a similar question.

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: I found a source that experienced the same exact error using Vuetify as wellL https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12516903#ans So perhaps maybe it is as simple as missing some import libs in the plugin? `import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'; // <---- add vuetify`

Answer (score 0):

Currently i haven't found a solution but an alternative in this article

[How to create a global snackbar using Nuxt, Vuetify and Vuex.](https://dev.to/stephann/how-to-create-a-global-snackbar-using-nuxt-vuetify-and-vuex-1bda)

IMHO this isn't as "clean" as a plugin since the listening component sits in `/layouts/default`  rather than the nuxt/vue context and therefore needs to be added it in all layouts to work.

I guess a workaround would be a "base" layout from which the all other layouts need to inherit

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this just now! I've been try to search for this for quite some time now as well.

You can access the root Vue instance used by Nuxt from the client as `window.$nuxt` (which is the same as `this.$root` inside the Vue components).

For your code, use `window.$nuxt.$vuetify.application` on the calling code.

NOTE: If you are using this on the plugin creation itself, make sure to wait for the Nuxt instance to be created first, by either doing a setTimeout, hooking through a module, or adding a component event, because the Nuxt instance has not been created yet.

EDIT: Fixed the sentence wording and added some insight.